# sum of all packets in pcap files

Tags: shell-script, pcap

I'm trying to make a simple bash script to calculate packets captured in pcap files, I used tcpdump to get packets in each pcap file and add them using a bash script but it doesnt seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/share/capture/*.pcap
sum =0
for f in $FILES
 do
  output=$(sudo tcpdump -r $f 2> /dev/null |wc -l)
  sum = $((output+ sum))
done
echo $sum
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have added spaces between assignment op ('=') and operands. Remove the spaces and you are good to go. For e.g. sum =0 should be sum=0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
files=(/share/capture/*.pcap)
#echo $files
sum=0
for f in "${files[@]}"
do
  output=`sudo tcpdump -r $f 2> /dev/null | wc -l`
  sum=$((output + sum))
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: Hi, i got a value, but it seems too small to be the correct value

Comment: You can cross verify it..execute `sudo tcpdump -r $f 2> /dev/null | wc -l` by assigning `f=/share/capture/1.pcap; sudo tcpdump -r $f 2> /dev/null | wc -l` and repeat it for (suppose 2.pcap, 3.pcap) & add all the values you get. Now put your script & only those pcap files in the same path & run again

Answer (score 2):

Just run `wc -l` on the output for all the files:

```
#!/bin/bash -
files=(/share/capture/*.pcap)

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  tcpdump -qr "$f" 2> /dev/null
done | wc -l
```

See also:

```
capinfos -rTc "${files[@]}"

capinfos -rTc "${files[@]}" | cut -f2 | paste -sd + | bc
```

(assuming file names don't contain TAB or NL characters).

Note that what you do:

```
FILES=/share/capture/*.pcap
```

You're assigning the string `/share/capture/*.pcap`, not the list of files to `$FILES`. That glob pattern is expanded when `$FILES` is referenced unquoted (the *split+glob* operator). Later on, you also leave `$f` unquoted, so invoke the split+glob operator again. So if `$f` contained blank characters or other wild cards it would be expanded to other files again. Best is to use an array here and make sure you quote all your variables.

Comment: Completely agreed